# Service worker registration failed and Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClicked')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm novice in Extension Developpement, I want to  build a simple extension that could replace of webpage paragraphs with written word in popup. I build it using ManifestV3 since V2 is obsolete.
Here are my tree files:

- "manifest.json"

```
    {
        "name": "Paragraph Replacer",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "manifest_version": 3,
        "description": "Paragraph Replacer",
        
        "background": {
          "service_worker": "background.js"
        },
    
        "content_scripts": [
          {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
              "js": ["contentscript.js"]
          }
        ],
        "permissions": ["activeTab"],
        "action":
         {
          "default_icon": "extension-logo.png",
          "default_popup": "popup.html"
         }
      }
```

- "contentscript.js"

```
    console.log("ContentScript ready");
    
    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
    
    function gotMessage(msg, sender, sendResponse)
    {
        console.log(msg.txt);
        if(msg.txt == "hello")
        {
            let pars = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
            for (elt of pars) {
                elt.innerHTML = message.txt;
              }
            
        }
    }
```

- "background.js"

```
 

    console.log("Background ready");
     chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);
    
     function buttonClicked(tab){
         let msg = {
            txt: "hello"
         };
    
       chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
       }
```

- **popup.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Paragraph</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Paragraph Replacer</h1>
    
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="par" id="userinput">
        </p>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

- **popup.js**

```
    let userinput = document.getElementById("userinput");
    
    userinput.addEventListener('input', newText);
    // userinput.input(newText);
    
    function newText(){
        console.log("Text Changed");
    
        let params = {
            active: true,
            currentWindow:true
        };
    
        chrome.tabs.query(params,gotTabs);
    
        function gotTabs(tabs)
        {
            let message = userinput.value();
    
            let msg = {
                txt: message
            };
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg);
    
        }
    
    }
```

When I reload my extension, The following errors popup:
[Service worker registration failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Zni.png)

[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onClicked')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk8U2.png)

Any helpful solution will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: 1) In ManifestV3 browserAction is just `action`. 2) `message` in contentscript should be `msg`, 3) Remove `if(msg.txt == "hello")`

Comment: Hey @wOxxOm, thanks for your help. Even I make changes, you suggest the same errors appear. ;/

Comment: After editing make sure to click the reload icon for your extension on chrome://extensions page. If it doesn't help, re-install the extension completely.